# Can not download Intellij via PPA - SSL certificate issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Hi am running Linux Mint 18.2 under VirtualBox (Windows host) and I have problem installing Intellij IDEA via PPA because of SSL certificate problem. 
Steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mmk2410/intellij-idea-community
sudo apt update
sudo apt install intellij-idea-community
```

Getting the following log:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  lib32ncurses5 lib32tinfo5 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev zlib1g-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  intellij-idea-community lib32ncurses5 lib32tinfo5 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/460 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,541 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package lib32tinfo5.
(Reading database ... 252386 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lib32tinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32tinfo5 (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32ncurses5.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32ncurses5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32ncurses5 (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32z1.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32z1_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32z1 (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zlib1g-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../zlib1g-dev_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zlib1g-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32z1-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32z1-dev_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32z1-dev (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../intellij-idea-community_2017.2.2-1_all.deb ...
--2017-08-29 17:48:04--  https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-2017.2.2.tar.gz
Resolving download-cf.jetbrains.com (download-cf.jetbrains.com)... 146.112.252.204, 146.112.252.210, 146.112.252.211, ...
Connecting to download-cf.jetbrains.com (download-cf.jetbrains.com)|146.112.252.204|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify download-cf.jetbrains.com's certificate, issued by ‘O=Cisco,CN=Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA lon-SG’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to download-cf.jetbrains.com insecurely, use ``--no-check-certificate'.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/intellij-idea-community_2017.2.2-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 5
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/intellij-idea-community_2017.2.2-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Of course I have the same SSL problem when trying downloading the idea manually from their website with chrome.
I could not find any thread regarding this issue but I know I could not recreate the problem with Ubuntu 16.04 (everything worked as expected).

Could some one provide me with explicit steps for solving this issue?

Comment: I don't get any SSL warnings when I try to access that URI - perhaps they (jetbrains)  have fixed their https setup? if not, your connection might be intercepted (e.g. a captive portal), in which case it is actually a *good thing* that you cannot access that page directly.

Comment: @umläute: Are you trying it with Mint 18.2? Because I tried it just now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @umläute: It is not a connection issue for sure since I have no problem downloading it with other operating system within the same network.

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue with failed certificates is a wrong system time.

So make sure that the time on your machine is (at approximately) correct, ideally by configuring `ntp` (but manually entering it might be good enough as well).

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntpdate
$ sudo ntpdate-debian
```

#### Explanation

certificates are only valid during in a certain timeframe, e.g. from *2017-04-20* until *2017-10-20*.
If your system has the time reset to (e.g.) *1970-01-01*, you will not be able to access the webpage (as from your system's POV the certificate is invalid)

Comment: The time on the machine is correct, it is not that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

before installing intellij-idea-community?

Comment: Yes, it is not that.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the problem further it seems to be related to the firewall in our office network.

Updating the /etc/resolv.conf to contain `nameserver 8.8.8.8` instead of `nameserver 127.0.1.1` solved the issue.